# Notification on android via Python using Pushsafer

Tags: android, python, push-notification

I am using "**Pushsafer**" to notify on my smartphone myself about the completion of my Python code execution. It worked fine for a couple of days, but now it is giving an error:

'"error": not enough API calls'

I am not able to figure out how to fix this.

Also, any other way to receive **notification on android via Python API** will also be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you've bought enough API calls to cover your usage? They do offer a small quota of free API calls for development and testing, but I don't know how large it is. As for alternatives, maybe [Join](https://joaoapps.com/join/) would be suitable?

Comment: Hello @kindall, You're right. After contacting them, I found out they indeed do have a limit on free API calls (around 20-30). I looked into [Join](https://joaoapps.com/join/) as you suggested but it is not what I need. I am actually looking for a way to notify me on my smartphone when my python script is finished executing. I looked into Google Cloud Messaging, but I'm not sure if that is what I need. Anyways, thanks for your reply.

Comment: You could use Slack. It's for organizations, but you could be an organization of one! I've used it for notifications related to scripts; the API is pretty straightforward to just post a message.

Comment: Perfect! Worked exactly as I wanted. Thanks @kindall